# Upwind differencing scheme in Finite Volume Method (FVM)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-volume-method

I have some troble in understanding how I can assess the direction of the flow for the upwind differencing scheme.

Lets say we have the following ODE:
$$a(x)\phi '(x)+b(x)\phi ''(x)=f(x)$$

> Now how do I asses the direction of the flow for this problem? I mean
>   is the flow in the positive $x$-direction or in the negative
>   $x$-direction?

I think it has to do something with the combination of the signs of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. I think if $\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}>0$ for the current control volume, then the flow is in the negative $x$-direction. If the ratio is negative, then the flow is in the positive $x$-direction.

> Is this right? And what happens if the one of the coefficients is
>   zero? In which direction is the flow then?

Another more complicated question is, how do I asses the flow direction in a PDE?

Lets consider the PDE for the scalar function $\phi(x,y)$. I will note partial derivatives with indices:

$$a(x,y)\phi_x+b(x,y)\phi_{xx}+c(x,y)\phi_{y}+d(x,y)\phi_{yy}=f(x,y)$$

> Can I use a similar approach by only considering the partial
>   derivatives in $x$ and $y$ separately?

Comment: What do you think about adding a "finite-volume-method" tag? Or should the existing "finite-differences" fit the bill already? Once upon a time, I've added the "finite-element-method" tag, which has been an achievement. What shall we do?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I think it makes sense to introduce a new tag. You can create it if you like:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a major flaw in the OP's (and many other people's) thinking.
Though it may be suggested by Classical Analysis all over the place, in Numerical Analysis *the boundary conditions can **not** be considered as being separate from the differential equation(s)*.
Both the ODE/PDE and the BC are an integral part of the problem numerically. We shall illustrate by the most dramatic simplification possible:
$$
b(x) = f(x) = 0 \quad ; \quad a(x) = \pm v \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{d\phi}{dx} = 0
$$
Where it is noticed that the information contained within $a(x) = \pm v$ has effectively disappeared.
Not so with the boundary conditions.
Let the integration domain be defined by $0 \le x \le L$, then there are two possible choices for the BC, say:
$$
\phi(0) = 1 \quad \mbox{xor} \quad \phi(L) = 1
$$
With $\phi(0) = 1$, the flow is in positive direction; with $\phi(L) = 1$, the flow is in negative direction.
And the upwind scheme must be adapted accordingly. Let the interval $0 \le x \le L$ be subdivided into
$N$ elements, then, with $k = 1,2,\cdots,N$ and $h = L/N$ :
$$
\frac{\phi_1-\phi_0}{h} = 0 \; , \;
\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{h} = 0 \; , \;
\cdots \; , \;
\frac{\phi_k-\phi_{k-1}}{h} = 0 \; , \;
\cdots \; , \;
\frac{\phi_N-\phi_{N-1}}{h} = 0
$$
$$ \begin{cases}
\phi_0 = 1 & \Longrightarrow & \phi_k := \phi_{k-1} & \mbox{starting with }\; k=1 \\
\phi_N = 1 & \Longrightarrow & \phi_{k-1} := \phi_k & \mbox{starting with }\; k=N \end{cases}
$$
With one and the same differential equation, there are two different numerical problems with two different schemes, finally.

**Update.** Q: "Is this right?" A: Yes and no. It depends entirely on the *physical interpretation* of the differential equation. The answer is yes if the ODE represents a *convection / diffusion problem*. But what if we augment it as follows:
$$
c(x)\phi(x)+a(x)\phi '(x)+b(x)\phi ''(x)=f(x)
$$
Then it can be an ODE for e.g. *damped oscillations* as well. And the latter is quite a different story numerically. Upwind differencing is a rather useless concept in that context (but I'm not an expert in the numerical treatment of wave equations). Similar arguments apply to the two-dimensional case. Additional reading:

- [2-D Elementary Substructures](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2004/purified.pdf)
- [Circuits on an arbitrary triangular lattice](https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Electric.html#Irregular)
- [Unified Numerical Analysis](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/index.htm)

BONUS. As a second example, consider a 2-D case : *pure convection of heat* . The OP's unknown function $\phi$ is identified with $T$ (temperature) in concordance with this.
$$
a(x,y)\phi_x+b(x,y)\phi_{xx}+c(x,y)\phi_{y}+d(x,y)\phi_{yy}=f(x,y) \\
b(x,y)=d(x,y)=f(x,y)=0 \quad ; \quad a(x,y)=u(x,y) \quad ; \quad c(x,y) = v(x,y) \\
\Longrightarrow \quad u(x,y)\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v(x,y)\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = 0
$$
Let the flow field be defined analytically by : $\;u(x,y) = x \; , \; v(x,y) = -y$ .

[image]

The discretization of the velocity field is:
$$
u = i \qquad ; \qquad v = - j
$$
The upwind scheme at a five point star is:
$$
U.(T_O-T_P) + V.(T_N-T_P) = 0
$$
In our case - look at the wind - it is seen that $U = u$ and $V = -v$ .
Working out the upwind scheme for the temperatures therefore results in:
$$
(i+j).T_{i,j} = i.T_{i-1,j} + j.T_{i,j+1}
$$
Assume a linear temperature profile on top, where the fluid comes in: $T_{i,3} = i$. The walls are always streamlines, hence $T_{0,j} = T_{i,0} = 0$. Now the temperatures in the rest of the field can be calculated by hand, for example:
$$
(1+2).T_{1,2} = 1.0 + 2.1 = 2 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad T_{1,2} = 2/3
$$
After six of these simple calculations the temperature field reads as follows:

```
        0     1     2     3
        0    2/3   4/3    2
        0    1/3   2/3    1
        0     0     0     0
```

Take a look at the temperature profile at the outflow opening: it is exactly as expected!
Even better. It can be proved that the discrete temperature field for an $N\times N$ grid
is given in general by: $T_{i,j} = i.j/N$ . Which corresponds *exactly* with the analytic solution: $T(x,y) = x.y$ .
Who has said that upwind schemes are somehow "less accurate"?
OK, and now *reverse all velocities* (change signs). This will *not* change the differential equation, but the inflow opening shall be at the former outflow opening. And the upwind scheme must be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Hmm .. now I am a little bit confused. Your ODE hast $T=$const. as solution. Why would there be a flow in the one or other direction? Or did you mean T(L)=-1 or some thing like that?

Comment: @MrYouMath: I've adapted the answer to be more in concordance with your question. Hope it's clearer now.