# Quadrilateral Interpolation

Tags: geometry, interpolation, finite-element-method, quadrilateral

The simplest finite element shape in two dimensions is a *triangle*.
In a finite element context, any geometrical shape is endowed with an **interpolation**,
which is *linear* for triangles (most of the time), as has been explained in
[**this answer**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541926/converting-triangles-to-isosceles-equilateral-or-right/542684#542684) :
$$
T(x,y) = A.x + B.y + C
$$
Here $A$ and $B$ can be expressed in coordinate and function values
at the vertices (nodal points) of the triangle:
$$
\begin{cases}
 A = [ (y_3 - y_1).(T_2 - T_1) - (y_2 - y_1).(T_3 - T_1) ] / \Delta  \\
 B = [ (x_2 - x_1).(T_3 - T_1) - (x_3 - x_1).(T_2 - T_1) ] / \Delta
\end{cases} \\ \Delta = (x_2 - x_1).(y_3 - y_1) - (x_3 - x_1).(y_2 - y_1)
$$
Consider the simplest finite element shape in two dimensions except one:
the **quadrilateral**. Function behavior inside a quadrilateral is approximated
by a **bilinear** interpolation between the function values at the vertices
or nodal points (most of the time.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_quadrilateral_element)
is rather terse about it)

Let $T$ be such a function, and $x,y$ coordinates. Then try:
$$
       T = A + B.x + C.y + D.x.y
$$
Giving:
$$
\begin{cases}
T_1 = A + B.x_1 + C.y_1 + D.x_1.y_1 \\
T_2 = A + B.x_2 + C.y_2 + D.x_2.y_2 \\
T_3 = A + B.x_3 + C.y_3 + D.x_3.y_3 \\ 
T_4 = A + B.x_4 + C.y_4 + D.x_4.y_4
\end{cases} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad 
\begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & y_1 & x_1 y_1 \\ 1 & x_2 & y_2 & x_2 y_2 \\
1 & x_3 & y_3 & x_3 y_3 \\ 1 & x_4 & y_4 & x_4 y_4 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{bmatrix} \\ \Longleftrightarrow \quad
\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & y_1 & x_1 y_1 \\ 1 & x_2 & y_2 & x_2 y_2 \\
1 & x_3 & y_3 & x_3 y_3 \\ 1 & x_4 & y_4 & x_4 y_4 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Provided that we have a non-singular matrix in the middle.

[image]

But now we have a little problem.
Consider the quadrilateral as depicted in the above picture on the right.
The vertex-coordinates of this quadrilateral are defined by the second and the
third column of the matrix below. This matrix is formed by specifying $T$
vertically for the nodal points and horizontally for the basic functions
$ 1,x,y,xy $ :
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4   \end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}  1  &  -\frac{1}{2}  &   0  &  0  \\
                  1  &   0  &  -\frac{1}{2}  &  0  \\
                  1  &  +\frac{1}{2}  &   0  &  0  \\
                  1  &   0  &  +\frac{1}{2}  &  0  \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{bmatrix}
$$
The last column of the matrix is zero. Hence it is *singular*, meaning that
$A,B,C$ and $D$ cannot be found in this manner. Though with a unstructured grid
there may seem to be not a great chance that a quadrilateral is exactly positioned
like this, experience reveals that it cannot be excluded that Murphy comes by.
That alone is enough reason to declare the method for triangles *not done* for quadrilaterals.

Two questions:

- Why in the first place would a *bilinear* interpolation be associated
  with a *quadrilateral*?
  Why not some other finite element shape?
  And why not some other interpolation?
- How can a bilinear interpolation be defined for an arbitrary quadrilateral (assumed *convex*),

  i.e. without running into singularities?

My problem is **not** so much **how** the quadrilateral and the bilinear are related **but** rather **why** they are related
in this way. I shall be satisfied with a response when it has become more clear that there are no other possibilities i.e. people haven't
overlooked anything.

EDIT. The comment by Rahul sheds some light. Let the finite element shape be "modified" by an affine
transformation (with $a,b,c,d,p,q$ arbitrary real constants) and work out for the term that is interesting:
$$\begin{cases}
x' = ax+by+p \\
y' = cx+dy+q
\end{cases} \quad \Longrightarrow \\
x'y'=acx^2+bdy^2 + (ad+bc)xy+(cp+aq)x+(dp+bq)y+pq
$$
So the interpolation *remains bilinear* only when the following conditions are fulfilled:
$$
ac=0 \; \wedge \; bd=0 \; \wedge \; ad+bc\ne 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \\ \begin{cases}
a\ne 0  \; \wedge \; d\ne 0 \; \wedge \; b=0 \; \wedge \; c=0 \\
a=0  \; \wedge \; d=0 \; \wedge \; b\ne 0 \; \wedge \; c\ne 0 \end{cases}\quad \Longleftrightarrow \\
\begin{cases}x'=ax+p\\y'=dy+q\end{cases} \quad \vee \quad \begin{cases}x'=by+p\\y'=cx+q\end{cases}
$$
This means that a (parent) quadrilateral element, once it has been chosen, can only be translated, scaled (in $x$- and/or $y$- direction),
mirrored in $\,y=\pm x$ , rotated over $90^o$. Did I forget something?

**Update.**

> Why a quadrilateral with bilinear interpolation?

Little else is possible with polynomial terms like $\;1,\xi,\eta,\xi\eta\,$ , if
four nodal points are needed (one degree of freedom each) for obtaining four
equations with four unknowns. Then stil there remain some issues, such as not
self-intersecting and being convex. The former issue has been covered in the
answer by Nominal Animal. The latter may be stuff for a separate question.

Other issues covered in the answer by Nominal Animal are the following.

- Perhaps the simplest heuristics is to take the *direct product* of one-dimensional case: the line segment as well as the linear interpolation. With the notations by Rahul and Nominal Animal that is: $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $\{1,u\}\times\{1,v\}$ . In the end, we have a square as the standard parent bilinear quadrilateral.
- For a non-degenerate **paralellogram** the bilinear interpolation is reduced to a **linear** one, which makes it simple to express the local coordinates $(u,v)$ into the global coordinates $(x,y)$.

LATE EDIT. Continuing story at:

- [Quadrilateral Finite Elements must be convex and not self-intersecting. But why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418151/quadrilateral-finite-elements-must-be-convex-and-not-self-intersecting-but-why)
- [Jacobian determinant for bi-linear Quadrilaterals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430691/jacobian-determinant-for-bi-linear-quadrilaterals)

Comment: The bilinear interpolation formula $T=A + Bx + Cy + Dxy$ only makes sense for axis-aligned rectangles, not for general quadrilaterals. One can see this by considering the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with all vertex values zero except $T_3=1$; the interpolating function is $T = xy$. Now rotate the square $45^\circ$; then the interpolating function should be simply the rotated version of $T = xy$. But that is $T = \frac12(y^2 - x^2)$, which is not of the above form.

Comment: I think we can parametrize(linearly) the quadrilateral to the unit square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$. The bilinear interpolation over unit square is standard, we 
calculate the interpolation over unit square, and then transfer the bilinear interpolation to the quadrilateral using parametrization. As @user856 said, we can't directly assume $T = A + Bx + Cy + Dxy$ over the quadrilateral, but we can assume $T = A + Bu + Cv + Duv$ over the unit square, then transfer it over the quadrilateral using parametrization.

Comment: I mean the parametrization of the quadrilateral can be chosen to be a linear(or affine) map when the quadrilateral is a parallelogram. Otherwise since the linear map only rotate, scale the unit square, the image of the linear parametrization must be a parallelogram, as a result we can't find a linear parametrization for an arbitrary quadrilateral. However, the parametrization can be at least $\textbf{bilinear}$, e.g. the one in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218523/parametrical-representations-of-polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewritten on 2016-11-12. The OP raised very good questions in the comments. Note that this is not intended as an exhaustive answer (as one might expect from, say, a mathematician?), but more like observations from someone who routinely uses bilinear interpolation for numerical data.

> How can a bilinear interpolation be defined for an arbitrary quadrilateral,
>   i.e. without running into singularities?

Bilinear interpolation is usually defined as
$$f(u,v) = (1-u) (1-v) F_{00} + u (1 - v) F_{01} + (1-u) v F_{10} + u v F_{11}$$
where $0 \le u, v \le 1$ and 
$$\begin{array}{}
f(0,0) = F_{00} \\
f(0,1) = F_{01} \\
f(1,0) = F_{10} \\
f(1,1) = F_{11} \\
f(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{F_{00}+F_{01}+F_{10}+F_{11}}{4}
\end{array}$$

If we use notation
$$p(t; p_0, p_1) = (1-t) p_0 + t p_1 = p_0 + t (p_1 - p_0)$$
for the simplest form of linear interpolation, with $0 \le t \le 1$, $p(0;p_0,p_1) = p_0$, $p(1;p_0,p_1) = p_1$, then bilinear interpolation can be written as
$$f(u,v) = p(u; p(v; F_{00}, F_{01}), p(v; F_{10}, F_{11}))$$
so this simply extends the single-variable linear interpolation to two variables and $2^2 = 4$ samples.

Bilinear interpolation is not often used for arbitrary quadrilaterals. After pondering the questions OP posed in the comments, I realized that the typical form used for interpolation,
$$\begin{cases}
x(u,v) = x_{00} + u ( x_{10} - x_{00}) + v ( x_{01} - x_{00} ) \\
y(u,v) = y_{00} + u ( y_{10} - y_{00}) + v ( y_{01} - y_{00} ) \\
f(u,v) = (1-v) \left ( (1-u) f_{00} + u f_{10} \right ) + (v) \left ( (1-u) f_{10} + u f_{11} \right )
\end{cases}$$
is not applicable to arbitrary quadrilaterals, as it assumes it to be a parallelogram, i.e. with
$$\begin{cases}
x_{11} = x_{10} + x_{01} - x_{00} \\
y_{11} = y_{10} + y_{01} - y_{00}
\end{cases}$$
Solving $x = x(u,v)$, $y = y(u,v)$ for $u$ and $v$ yields
$$\begin{cases}
A = x_{00} (y_{01} - y_{10}) + x_{01} (y_{10} - y_{00}) + x_{10} (y_{00} - y_{01}) \\
u = \frac{ (x_{01} - x_{00}) y - (y_{01} - y_{00}) x + x_{00} y_{01} - y_{00} x_{01} }{A} \\
v = \frac{ (x_{00} - x_{10}) y - (y_{00} - y_{10}) x - x_{00} y_{10} + y_{00} x_{10} }{A}
\end{cases}$$
where $$A = \left(\vec{p}_{10} - \vec{p}_{00}\right) \times \left(\vec{p}_{01} - \vec{p}_{00}\right)$$
where $\times$ signifies the 2D analog of vector cross product, so $\lvert A \rvert$ is the area of the parallelogram. Thus, exactly one solution exists for all non-degenerate parallelograms.

For the most common use case, a regular rectangular axis-aligned grid of samples $p_{ji}$, $0 \le j, i \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$\begin{cases}
x = a_x + b_x i \\
y = a_y + b_y j
\end{cases}$$
with $b_x \ne 0$, $b_y \ne 0$, corresponding to interpolation parameters
$$\begin{cases}
i = \left\lfloor \frac{x - a_x}{b_x} \right\rfloor \\
j = \left\lfloor \frac{y - a_y}{b_y} \right\rfloor \\
u = \frac{x - a_x}{b_x} - i \\
v = \frac{y - a_y}{b_y} - j
\end{cases}$$
so that
$$p(x,y) = (1-v) \left ( (1-u) p_{j,i} + (u) p_{j,i+1} \right ) + (v) \left ( (1-u) p_{j+1,i} + (u) p_{j+1,i+1} \right )$$

To apply bilinear interpolation to an arbitrary quadrilateral, we need to use
$$\begin{cases}
x(u,v) = (1-u)(1-v) x_{00} + (u)(1-v) x_{10} + (1-u)(v) x_{01} + (u)(v) x_{11} \\
y(u,v) = (1-u)(1-v) y_{00} + (u)(1-v) y_{10} + (1-u)(v) y_{01} + (u)(v) y_{11} \\
f(u,v) = (1-u)(1-v) f_{00} + (u)(1-v) f_{10} + (1-u)(v) f_{01} + (u)(v) f_{11}
\end{cases}$$
In some cases it is sufficient to produce additional samples, for example so that each quadrilateral can be split into four sub-quadrilaterals, doubling the resolution. Then, we do not need to solve for $x$ and $y$, and only need to compute
$$\begin{array}{cc}
x\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right), & y\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right), & f\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right) \\
x\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right), & y\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right), & f\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right) \\
x\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right), & y\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right), & f\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
x\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right), & y\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right), & f\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{array}$$

However, solving $(u,v)$ for some specific $(x,y)$ is quite complicated. Indeed, I was surprised how complicated it turns out to be! (I apologize for misrepresenting this case as "easy" in a previous edit. Mea culpa.)

In practice, we first try to solve $u$ or $v$, and then the other by substituting into one of the equations above. If we decide we wish to solve $u$ first, we need to solve
$$U_2 u^2 + U_1 u + U_0 = 0$$
where
$$\begin{cases}
U_2 = (y_{00}-y_{01}) (x_{10}-x_{11}) - (x_{00}-x_{01}) (y_{10}-y_{11}) \\
U_1 = (y_{00}-y_{01}-y_{10}+y_{11}) x - (x_{00}-x_{01}-x_{10}+x_{11}) y + (x_{11}-2 x_{10}) y_{00} + (2 x_{00}-x_{01}) y_{10} + y_{01} x_{10} - y_{11} x_{00} \\
U_0 = (y_{10}-y_{00}) x - (x_{10}-x_{00}) y + y_{00} x_{10} - x_{00} y_{10}
\end{cases}$$
The possible solutions are
$$\begin{cases}
u = \frac{-U_1 \pm \sqrt{ U_1^2 - 4 U_2 U_0}}{2 U_2}, & U_2 \ne 0 \\
u = \frac{-U_0}{U_1}, & U_2 = 0, U_1 \ne 0 \\
u = 0, & U_2 = 0, U_0 = 0
\end{cases}$$
If we find $0 \le u \le 1$, we solve for $v$ by substituting into $X(u,v) = x$,
$$v = \frac{ (y_{00} - y_{10}) u + y - y_{00} }{ (y_{00} - y_{01} - y_{10} + y_{11}) u - y_{00} + y_{01} }$$
or into $Y(u,v) = y$,
$$v = \frac{ (x_{00} - x_{10}) u + x - x_{00} }{ (x_{00} - x_{01} - x_{10} + x_{11}) u - x_{00} + x_{01} }$$

If we find no solutions, we try to solve for $v$ in
$$V_2 v^2 + V_1 v + V_0 = 0$$
where
$$\begin{cases}
V_2 = (x_{00}-x_{01}) (y_{10}-y_{11}) - (y_{00}-y_{01}) (x_{10}-x_{11}) \\
V_1 = (x_{00}-x_{01}-x_{10}+x_{11}) y - (y_{00}-y_{01}-y_{10}+y_{11}) x + (y_{11}-2 y_{10}) x_{00} + (2 y_{00}-y_{01}) x_{10} + x_{01} y_{10} - x_{11} y_{00} \\
V_0 = (x_{10}-x_{00}) y - (y_{10}-y_{00}) x + x_{00} y_{10} - y_{00} x_{10}
\end{cases}$$
The possible solutions are similar to those for $u$:
$$\begin{cases}
v = \frac{-V_1 \pm \sqrt{ V_1^2 - 4 V_2 V_0}}{2 V_2}, & V_2 \ne 0 \\
v = \frac{-V_0}{V_1}, & V_2 = 0, V_1 \ne 0 \\
v = 0, & V_2 = 0, V_0 = 0
\end{cases}$$
If you find $0 \le v \le 1$, you solve for $u$ by substituting into $X(u,v) = x$,
$$u = \frac{(x_{00} - x_{01}) v + x - x_{00} }{ (x_{00} - x_{01} - x_{10} + x_{11}) v - x_{00} + x_{10} }$$
or into $Y(u,v) = y$,
$$u = \frac{(y_{00} - y_{01}) v + y - y_{00} }{ (y_{00} - y_{01} - y_{10} + y_{11}) v - y_{00} + y_{10} }$$

It is also possible to solve $(u,v)$ numerically, by calculating $X(u,v)$ and $Y(u,v)$ repeatedly with different $u$, $v$, until $\lvert X(u,v) - x \rvert \le \epsilon$ and $\lvert Y(u,v) - y \rvert \le \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the maximum acceptable error in $x$ and $y$ (maximum distance to correct $(x,y)$ being $\sqrt{2}\epsilon$).

There are a number of different methods for the numerical search. Some of the following observations may come in handy, when implementing a numerical search:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\frac{d \, X(u,v)}{d\,u} = & x_{10} - x_{00} + v ( x_{11} - x_{01} - x_{10} + x_{00} ) \\
\frac{d \, X(u,v)}{d\,v} = & x_{01} - x_{00} + u ( x_{11} - x_{01} - x_{10} + x_{00} ) \\
\frac{d \, Y(u,v)}{d\,u} = & y_{10} - y_{00} + v ( y_{11} - y_{01} - y_{10} + y_{00} ) \\
\frac{d \, Y(u,v)}{d\,v} = & y_{01} - y_{00} + u ( y_{11} - y_{01} - y_{10} + y_{00} ) \\
X(u + du, v) - X(u, v) = & du \left ( x_{10} - x_{00} + v ( x_{11} - x_{01} - x_{10} + x_{00} ) \right ) \\
X(u, v + dv) - X(u, v) = & dv \left ( x_{01} - x_{00} + u ( x_{11} - x_{01} - x_{10} + x_{00} ) \right ) \\
Y(u + du, v) - Y(u, v) = & du \left ( y_{10} - y_{00} + v ( y_{11} - y_{01} - y_{10} + y_{00} ) \right ) \\
Y(u, v + dv) - Y(u, v) = & dv \left ( y_{01} - y_{00} + u ( y_{11} - y_{01} - y_{10} + y_{00} ) \right )
\end{array}$$

In other words, it is true that the bilinear interpolation is quite difficult for arbitrary quadrilaterals, and very problematic for self-intersecting quadrilaterals. However, the most common quadrilateral types -- rectangles and parallelograms -- are easy, and even the general case is solvable at least numerically, even in the presence of singularities.

---

> Why bilinear interpolation with quadrilaterals?

As I've shown above, for the rectangles and parallelograms -- the only quadrilaterals I've used bilinear interpolation with in real solutions --, bilinear interpolation is easy and simple.

Indeed, the emphasis on *quadrilaterals* (in the sense of arbitrary quadrilaterals) seems incorrect, as bilinear interpolation is mostly used with rectangles or parallelograms.

Perhaps the emphasis should be on that bilinear interpolation uses two variables to interpolate between four known values; or more generally, $k$-linear interpolation uses $k$ variables to interpolate between $2^k$ values. Trilinear interpolation is similarly common for cuboids with vertices
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{p}_{011} = \vec{p}_{010} + \vec{p}_{001} - \vec{p}_{000} \\
\vec{p}_{101} = \vec{p}_{100} + \vec{p}_{001} - \vec{p}_{000} \\
\vec{p}_{110} = \vec{p}_{100} + \vec{p}_{010} - \vec{p}_{000} \\
\vec{p}_{111} = \vec{p}_{100} + \vec{p}_{010} + \vec{p}_{001} - 2 \vec{p}_{000}
\end{cases}$$
i.e. cuboids defined by one vertex and three edge vectors.

Regular grids are ubiquitous, and linear mapping is the simplest interpolation method, with easy properties. Cubic interpolation and other interpolation methods do produce better results, but are computationally more expensive, and the properties may produce unwanted behaviour: most typically, the interpolated value is no longer guaranteed to reside within the range spanned by the constants.

Comment: 1. It is implicitly but not explicitly assumed in your answer that the interpolation is at Rahul's standard unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ ;
only _then_ it is trivial, but there are other possibilities. 2. (+1) for the notation $F_{00,01,10,11}$ that I haven't seen before.

Comment: 3. I've also noticed the _self-intersecting_ issue in your answer and concordingly augmented the question, with the even stronger
requirement that FE quadrilaterals must be _convex_. 4. When trying to solve for $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ then the result in general
is __not__ bilinear, as claimed in your answer (?). With MAPLE, I get some result with $x^2$ , $y^2$ and a square root involved.
Indeed there are two solutions $(u,v)$ , but they are not "simple".

Comment: @HandeBruijn: 1. True. The assumption is typical in all implementations I've encountered (as is the notation in 2., especially in multivariate interpolation). I have not seen any reason to use any other interpolation interval thus far (for nonintersecting/convex quadrilaterals), which I believe it is the reason I glossed over that.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: 3. Astute observation, and very nicely formulated; I shall steal that from you the next time I write up such an interpolation. :) 4. No, I did not intend to imply the inverse is bilinear, it definitely is not. As to "simple", let me see if I can dig up the simplified solution to the results from Maple (as Maple does not give you the simplest form even via `optimize(, tryhard)` from `codegen`.

Comment: Your answer has become good enough for an accept. But I hope you will stay in contact with the question (for example by having it as a favorite?)
because I'm in the process of posting another answer of my own, which might contain a few surprises :-)

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Actually, I like your answer better than mine :). I can certainly see your approach is much more robust and methodical; after all, I simply explored the solutions used in practice, not their mathematical definitions -- simply because I am not a mathematician, and do not have sufficient skill or experience on that side.

Comment: There's no need to underestimate the impact of your feedback, coming from practice. Actually, you keep me going on the subject in this way :-) And yes, I've seen that you have an impressive (15k) reputation count elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Why a bilinear interpolation with a quadrilateral?

As pointed out in the EDIT of the question, this issue is a bit more subtle.

At first the comment by Rahul is applied here as a heuristics.
Rotate our $[-1,+1]×[-1,+1]$ square over $45^o$, with $xy \to \frac{1}{2}(y^2-x^2)$ as a consequence.
Instead of the basic polynomial $\,xy\,$ one gets two basic polynomials $x^2$ and $y^2$, five in total :
$1,x,y,x^2,y^2$ . For the basic shape this would imply *five* nodal points instead of four.
Now take a look at the picture below: an extra nodal point $(0)$ in the middle has been provided.

[image]

The shape on the right side is known in Finite Difference circles as a **five point star**.
It will be demonstrated here that it is possible to treat this Finite Difference pencil as if
it were a Finite Element. Let the coordinates of the *parent* five point star be given by:
$$
(0) = (0,0) \quad ; \quad \begin{cases} (1) = (-1,0) \quad ; \quad (2) = (+1,0) \\
(3) = (0,-1) \quad ; \quad (4) = (0,+1)\end{cases}
$$
Let function behaviour "inside" the five point star be approximated by a quadratic interpolation
between the function values at the vertices or nodal points, let $T$ be such a function and use
its Taylor expansion around the origin $(0)$:
$$
T(\xi,\eta) = T(0) + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}(0).\xi
         + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta}(0).\eta
         + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \xi^2}(0).\xi^2
         + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \eta^2}(0).\eta^2
$$
Specify $T$ for the vertices with the basic polynomials of the five point star:
$$
T_0 = T(0)\\
T_1 = T(0) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}(0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \xi^2}(0)\\
T_2 = T(0) + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}(0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \xi^2}(0)\\
T_3 = T(0) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta}(0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \eta^2}(0)\\
T_4 = T(0) + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta}(0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \eta^2}(0)\\
\quad \mbox{ F.E. } \leftarrow \mbox{ F.D. }
$$
Solving these equations is not much of a problem
and well-known Finite Difference schemes are recognized:
$$
  T(0) = T_0 \\
  \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}(0) = \frac{T_2-T_1}{2}\\
  \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta}(0) = \frac{T_4-T_3}{2} \\
  \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \xi^2}(0) = T_1-2T_0+T_2 \\
  \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \eta^2}(0) = T_3-2T_0+T_4 \\
\quad \mbox{ F.D. } \leftarrow \mbox{ F.E. }
$$
Finite Element shape functions may be constructed as follows:
$$
T = N_0.T_0 +  N_1.T_1 + N_2.T_2 + N_3.T_3 + N_4.T_4 = \\
T_0 + \frac{T_2-T_1}{2}\xi + \frac{T_4-T_3}{2}\eta
+ \frac{T_1-2T_0+T_2}{2}\xi^2 + \frac{T_3-2T_0+T_4}{2}\eta^2 =\\
(1-\xi^2-\eta^2)T_0 + \frac{1}{2}(-\xi+\xi^2)T_1 + \frac{1}{2}(+\xi+\xi^2)T_2
+\frac{1}{2}(-\eta+\eta^2)T_3 + \frac{1}{2}(+\eta+\eta^2)T_4 \\ \Longrightarrow \quad
  \begin{cases}
  N_0 = 1-\xi^2-\eta^2 \\
  N_1 = (-\xi+\xi^2)/2\\
  N_2 = (+\xi+\xi^2)/2\\
  N_3 = (-\eta+\eta^2)/2\\
  N_4 = (+\eta+\eta^2)/2
  \end{cases}
$$
It is assumed that the *same parameters* $(\xi,\eta)$ are employed for the function $T$
as well as for the (global Cartesian) coordinates $x$ and $y$. Herewith it is expressed that
we have, as with the linear triangle and the bilinear quadrilateral, an *isoparametric
transformation*:
$$
\begin{cases}
   x = N_0.x_0 + N_1.x_1 + N_2.x_2 + N_3.x_3 + N_4.x_4 \\
   y = N_0.y_0 + N_1.y_1 + N_2.y_2 + N_3.y_3 + N_4.y_4
\end{cases} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
   x =& x_0 + (x_2-x_1)/2\cdot\xi + (x_4-x_3)/2\cdot\eta\\
 &+ \left[(x_1+x_2)/2-x_0\right]\cdot\xi^2 + \left[(x_3+x_4)/2-x_0\right]\cdot\eta^2 \\
   y =& y_0 + (y_2-y_1)/2\cdot\xi + (y_4-y_3)/2\cdot\eta\\
 &+ \left[(y_1+y_2)/2-y_0\right]\cdot\xi^2 + \left[(y_3+y_4)/2-y_0\right]\cdot\eta^2
\end{cases}
$$
Now take a look at the picture below and let attention be shifted from the original quadrilateral
to the quadrilateral that joins the midpoints of the edges of the original. The latter is known as
the [**Varignon parallelogram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem)
and it may be associated with our five point star.

[image]

When doing so, the diagonals of the parallelogram become the local coordinate axes of the star and
by a well-known property of the diagonals of a parallelogram we have:
$$
\begin{cases} x_0 = (x_1+x_2)/2 \\ x_0 = (x_3+x_4)/2 \end{cases} \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\begin{cases} y_0 = (y_1+y_2)/2 \\ y_0 = (y_3+y_4)/2 \end{cases} \quad \Longrightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
   x = x_0 + (x_2-x_1)/2.\xi + (x_4-x_3)/2.\eta \\
   y = y_0 + (y_2-y_1)/2.\xi + (y_4-y_3)/2.\eta
\end{cases}
$$
Swithing [**back**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007116/quadrilateral-interpolation/2012594#2012594) to the (numbering of) the original quadrilateral (on the left in the picture) we have:
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{array}{l}
   x(\xi,\eta) = A_x + B_x.\xi + C_x.\eta\cancel{+ D_x.\xi.\eta} \\
   y(\xi,\eta) = A_y + B_y.\xi + C_y.\eta\cancel{+ D_y.\xi.\eta}
\end{array} \qquad \mbox{ where: } \\
\begin{array}{ll}
  A_x = \frac{1}{4} ( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 ) & ; \quad
  A_y = \frac{1}{4} ( y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 ) \\
  B_x = \frac{1}{4} \left[(x_2 + x_4) - (x_1 + x_3)\right] & ; \quad
  B_y = \frac{1}{4} \left[(y_2 + y_4) - (y_1 + y_3)\right] \\
  C_x = \frac{1}{4} \left[(x_3 + x_4) - (x_1 + x_2)\right] & ; \quad
  C_y = \frac{1}{4} \left[(y_3 + y_4) - (y_1 + y_2)\right] \\
  \cancel{D_x = \frac{1}{4} ( + x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4 )} & ; \quad
  \cancel{D_y = \frac{1}{4} ( + y_1 - y_2 - y_3 + y_4 )}
\end{array}
$$
Which is precisely the original bilinear interpolation,
where the non-linear $\,\xi.\eta\,$ terms simply have been erased.
Due to the linearity achieved, the local parameters $(\xi,\eta)$ can easily be expressed now in the global coordinates $(x,y)$  :
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \xi \\ \eta \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} B_x & C_x \\ B_y & C_y \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} x-A_x \\ y-A_y \end{bmatrix}
$$
Because of the *isoparametrics*, exactly the same interpolation is applicable to any other
function $T$. Substitute $\,\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y)\,$ in:
$$
   T(\xi,\eta) = A_T + B_T.\xi + C_T.\eta
\quad \mbox{ where: } \quad
\begin{cases}
  A_T = \frac{1}{4} ( T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4 ) \\
  B_T = \frac{1}{4} \left[(T_2 + T_4) - (T_1 + T_3)\right] \\
  C_T = \frac{1}{4} \left[(T_3 + T_4) - (T_1 + T_2)\right]
\end{cases}
$$
The idea is to evaluate function values at the midpoints of the edges of the bilinear quadrilateral.
Joining these midpoints together gives the Varignon parallelogram. Then employ the now *linear* interpolation of
this parallelogram as an extrapolation for points inside the original quadrilateral (under the assumption
that there is no problem with determining if a point is inside/outside an arbitrary convex quadrilateral
within an unstructured grid). Here is a visualization of the substitute interpolation. The original
quadrilateral is in black (with red vertices), the Varignon parallelogram is in blue, the $(\xi,\eta)$
coordinate axes are in yellow, the area covered by the substitute interpolation, with $-1 < \xi+\eta < +1$ and $-1 < \xi-\eta < +1$ , is in grey. There are four
[**triangles**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541926/converting-triangles-to-isosceles-equilateral-or-right/542684#542684) remaining.

[image]

LATE EDIT. Continuing story at:

#### [Any employment for the Varignon parallelogram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023382/any-employment-for-the-varignon-parallelogram)

Comment: I used this to interpolate between four values $z$, defined at the vertices of the original quadrilateral. Any attempt to fit a $z(u, v)$ (with $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ corresponding to the Varignon parallelogram vertices), using form $z(u,v) = z_0 + u z_u + v z_v$ exactly to those leads to singularities ($u v z_{uv}$ term does not help). If $x(u,v) = x_0 + u x_u + v x_v$, $y(u,v) = y_0 + u y_u + v y_v$, but $z(u,v) = z_0 + u z_u + v z_v + u^2 z_{uu} + v^2 z_{vv}$, this works, matching exactly at center, edge midpoints, and at original quadrilateral vertices, but $z$ is not linear anymore. Head hurts.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Oops! Yes. Of course. Because the interpolations across the quadrilateral boundaries have become __discontinuous__ now. Therefore the above does not really resolve that issue in your answer. Maybe it is useful for some other purpose though, so I'll
leave it the way it is. Sorry for being the cause of your headache.

Comment: Right -- but instead of this formulation, we could then just use bilinear interpolation for the Varignon parallelogram, and separate bilinear ones for the four triangles; it would be continuous throughout. In any case, I only have my weak math-fu to blame for the pain :). I will see if I can write the solver (in C) for the general case; it might just be that the $-1 \le u, v \le +1$ parametrization might make the singularities and degenerate cases easier to manage. If it passes muster, I shall add it to my answer here, just for future reference.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I've adapted the answer accordingly. Indeed it must be $-1 \le u\pm v \le +1$ instead of $-1 \le u, v \le +1$. But now I have the uneasy feeling that we could have used any triangulation of the quad, which would have saved us a lot of work.

Comment: I've made some progress on the purely numerical side, but encountered surprising numerical instability (or numerical error) wrt. quadrilaterals with three vertices nearly collinear, at points where the $u$ and $v$ axes are almost parallel. Overall speed is not an issue -- thus far, it looks like interpolating a function bilinearly within an arbitrary quadrilateral, given the $x$, $y$ coordinates, should take a comparable time to evaluating one trigonometric function --, but I worry there is an approach I'm not seeing. I shall experiment more, and report back if I find anything really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not meant as a duplicate of someone else's answer - hope it's complementary,
but I want this section to be coherent and complete, for future reference as well.
Apologies if things have become somewhat overdone.

The parent element that will be adopted for
our own purpose is *not quite the unit* square. Instead it is:
$\,[-1,+1]\times[-1,+1]$ . And the local coordinates inside our parent quadrilateral
are defined accordingly: $\,-1 \leq \xi \leq +1\,$ and $\,-1 \leq \eta \leq +1\,$ . It's
the same material as employed by Rahul and Nominal Animal if we only substitute
$\,\xi = 2u-1$ and $\eta = 2v-1\;$ i.e. translation and scaling of the same shape
(see the question's EDIT). The *node numbering* as proposed by Nominal Animal
has been implemented here as follows: $\,\operatorname{nr}(x,y) = 2y+x+1\,$
with $\,x \in \{0,1\}\,$ and $\,y \in \{0,1\}$ .
The advantage being that, in contrast with the more common counterclockwise convention,
such a numbering can be generalized smoothly to three dimensions and higher.

[image]

Okay, whatever. Let function behaviour inside a FEM quadrilateral be approximated 
by a bilinear interpolation between the function values at the vertices or nodal points, let $T$ be such a function:
$$
T = A_T + B_T.\xi + C_T.\eta + D_T.\xi.\eta
$$
It is assumed that the *same parameters* $(\xi,\eta)$ are employed for the function
$T$ as well as for the (global Cartesian) coordinates $x$ and $y$. Herewith it is
expressed that we have, as with the linear triangle, an *isoparametric transformation*:
$$
x = A_x + B_x.\xi + C_x.\eta + D_x.\xi.\eta \\
y = A_y + B_y.\xi + C_y.\eta + D_y.\xi.\eta
$$
Now specify any function $T$ for the vertices and the basic functions:
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix} +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 \\
                  +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 \\
                  +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
                  +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} A_T \\ B_T \\ C_T \\ D_T \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \mbox{ F.E } \leftarrow \mbox{ F.D. }
$$
It is remarked that the above matrix is *orthogonal*, i.e. its columns are
mutually perpendicular. This also means that the "condition" of the matrix is
optimal. Even better, it is similar to the well-known $4\times 4$
[Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix).
Apart from a scaling factor $4$, the inverse matrix is equal to the transpose,
which can be determined easily:
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} A_T \\ B_T \\ C_T \\ D_T \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{4}
  \begin{bmatrix}  +1  &  +1  &  +1  &  +1 \\
                   -1  &  +1  &  -1  &  +1 \\
                   -1  &  -1  &  +1  &  +1 \\
                   +1  &  -1  &  -1  &  +1 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \mbox{ F.D } \leftarrow \mbox{ F.E. }
$$
Writing out the matrix notation:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
  A_T = \frac{1}{4} ( + T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4 ) \\
  B_T = \frac{1}{4} ( - T_1 + T_2 - T_3 + T_4 ) \\
  C_T = \frac{1}{4} ( - T_1 - T_2 + T_3 + T_4 ) \\
  D_T = \frac{1}{4} ( + T_1 - T_2 - T_3 + T_4 )
\end{array}
$$
Hence $A_T,B_T,C_T,D_T$ are equal to local partial derivatives:
$$
 T(0) = A_T \quad ; \quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}(0) = B_T \quad ; \quad
 \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta}(0) = C_T \quad ; \quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi \partial \eta} = D_T
$$
These coefficients form a Finite Difference formulation:
$$
T = T(0) + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}(0).\xi + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta}(0).\eta
         + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}.\xi.\eta
$$
Shape functions may be constructed as follows:
$$
     T = N_1.T_1 + N_2.T_2 + N_3.T_3 + N_4.T_4 =
\begin{bmatrix} N_1 & N_2 & N_3 & N_4 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \end{bmatrix} =\\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \xi & \eta & \xi.\eta \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A_T \\ B_T \\ C_T \\ D_T \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \xi & \eta & \xi.\eta \end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4}
  \begin{bmatrix}  +1  &  +1  &  +1  &  +1 \\
                   -1  &  +1  &  -1  &  +1 \\
                   -1  &  -1  &  +1  &  +1 \\
                   +1  &  -1  &  -1  &  +1 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \end{bmatrix} \quad \Longrightarrow \\
  \begin{bmatrix} N_1 & N_2 & N_3 & N_4 \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \xi & \eta & \xi.\eta \end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4}
  \begin{bmatrix}  +1  &  +1  &  +1  &  +1 \\
                   -1  &  +1  &  -1  &  +1 \\
                   -1  &  -1  &  +1  &  +1 \\
                   +1  &  -1  &  -1  &  +1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \Longrightarrow \\
  \begin{array}{l}
  N_1 = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \xi - \eta + \xi.\eta) =
  \frac{1}{4}(1 - \xi).(1 - \eta)\\
  N_2 = \frac{1}{4}(1 + \xi - \eta - \xi.\eta) =
  \frac{1}{4}(1 + \xi).(1 - \eta)\\
  N_3 = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \xi + \eta - \xi.\eta) =
  \frac{1}{4}(1 - \xi).(1 + \eta)\\
  N_4 = \frac{1}{4}(1 + \xi + \eta + \xi.\eta) =
  \frac{1}{4}(1 + \xi).(1 + \eta)
\end{array}
$$
Any shape function $N_k$ has a value $1$ at vertex $(k)$ and it is zero at all
other vertices. The global and local coordinates of an arbitrary quadrilateral are related to each other via:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
   x = N_1.x_1 + N_2.x_2 + N_3.x_3 + N_4.x_4 \\
   y = N_1.y_1 + N_2.y_2 + N_3.y_3 + N_4.y_4
\end{array} $$
The equivalent Finite Difference representation is:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
   x(\xi,\eta) = A_x + B_x.\xi + C_x.\eta + D_x.\xi.\eta \\
   y(\xi,\eta) = A_y + B_y.\xi + C_y.\eta + D_y.\xi.\eta
\end{array} \qquad \mbox{ where: } $$
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
  A_x = \frac{1}{4} ( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 ) & ; \quad
  A_y = \frac{1}{4} ( y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 ) \\
  B_x = \frac{1}{4} \left[(x_2 + x_4) - (x_1 + x_3)\right] & ; \quad
  B_y = \frac{1}{4} \left[(y_2 + y_4) - (y_1 + y_3)\right] \\
  C_x = \frac{1}{4} \left[(x_3 + x_4) - (x_1 + x_2)\right] & ; \quad
  C_y = \frac{1}{4} \left[(y_3 + y_4) - (y_1 + y_2)\right] \\
  D_x = \frac{1}{4} ( + x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4 ) & ; \quad
  D_y = \frac{1}{4} ( + y_1 - y_2 - y_3 + y_4 )
\end{array} $$
The origin of the local $(\xi,\eta)$ coordinate system is determined by
$\xi=0$ and $\eta=0$.
Hence by $(A_x,A_y) = (\overline{x},\overline{y})$ =
midpoint = centroid.
The $\xi$-axis is defined by $-1 < \xi < +1$ and $\eta = 0$.
Hence by the (dashed) line $(x,y) = (A_x,A_y) + \xi. (B_x,B_y) $.
The $\eta$-axis is defined by $-1 < \eta < +1$ and $\xi = 0$.
Hence by the (dashed) line $(x,y) = (A_x,A_y) + \eta. (C_x,C_y) $.

Comment: Have you worked out the inverse of the shape functions $N_k$; i.e. solving $(\xi, \eta)$ when $(x,y)$ is within the quadrilateral? This is the painful bit (but fortunately rarely needed), and I was wondering if the changes in parametrization make it easier.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: That's another issue triggered by your answer that I'm processing now and if successful, it will become another answer of my own. A possible clue is to replace the bilinear interpolation by a _linear_ one, by using sort of an optimal covering _parallellogram_ (called substitute shape functions in FEM? I don't know)

Comment: So true! Simply assign the parallelogram vertices with values that result in correct values at quadrilateral vertices. Problem: How to define the parallelogram, without becoming dependent on the quadrilateral orientation and/or shape? For a perfect solution, the interpolation along each quadrilateral edge would be linear; it seems hard to impossible to achieve in the general case (is it?). Would it actually matter in practice? As long as it reduces to linear in the true parallelogram/rectangle cases (so no discontinuities occur in a non-regular grid), I think this would work fine.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: The idea is to evaluate function values at the _midpoints_ of the edges of the quadrilateral. Joining these midpoints together gives the [Varignon parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem). Then use the _linear_ interpolation of this parallelogram as an extrapolation for points inside the original quadrilateral (while assuming that there is no problem with determining if a point is inside/outside an arbitrary convex quadrilateral
within an unstructured grid). Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, the Varignon parallelogram is exactly what I was grasping at, but knew nothing about until you mentioned it. I think I'll put Maple to work later today, to find out exactly how that would work in practice; this is very interesting, and real-world applicable.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Please take notice of another answer. I'm not cheating: some elements of it have only be discovered in the last few days. Thanks again for your inspiring feedback.